# error to delete files older than 1 day from csv list

Tags: sh, ksh, aix

I want to delete files in a directory, from the supplies csv file if its older than 1 day.

I tried to print them for test purpose:

in.txt

```
1,one
2,two
```

code:

```
 INPUT="in.txt"
 while IFS=',' read -r id name
 do
   find tmp/$name -mtime +1 -type f
 done < "$INPUT"
```

This code throws error :

```
find: bad status-- tmp/one
find: bad status-- tmp/two
```

Thanks.

Comment: try `find tmp -name $name -mtime ...` Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

recall that the form for a `find` command is

```
 find ${baseDir} -${options ......} args to opts.
```

Your form is saying

```
find tmp/$name -mtime +1 -type f
# --^^^^^^^^^^ -- start looking in dir tmp/$name
```

You probably want to say

```
find tmp -name $name -mtime +1 -type f
#---^^^^^ start looking in the tmp dir
```

Keeping the `-type f` may not be needed, but it prevents you from matching a directory instead of a file.

IHTH.